# Expected value of red/blue ball game

Tags: probability

There are 4 red balls and 3 blue balls in an urn. Picking red balls gives you 1 dollar and picking blue balls means you have to pay 1 dollar. You can stop picking balls at any point.

What is the expected value of this game, given that you play rationally? Rationally means that you will stop drawing more balls when you know that the EV is negative.

Someone suggested using backwards induction (creating a matrix from 0,0 to 3,4) but I need some help, as I don't know how to use this.

Comment: The suggestion is: calculate the expected value for 20 different variants of this game, where the number of red balls is anywhere from 0 to 4 and the number of blue balls is anywhere from 0 to 3. The calculation of the expected value of the game with $r$ red balls and $b$ blue balls (the "$(r,b)$ game") is trivial if either $r=0$ or $b=0$, and otherwise it's pretty easy if you already know the expected values of the $(r-1,b)$ and $(r,b-1)$ games. So calculate these expected values starting with $r=b=0$ and work your way upwards to $r=4,b=3$.

Comment: @GregMartin Thank you! So, by (r,b), do you mean when r red balls and b blue balls are remaining to be picked? If yes: Just to run through a quick example; I would see that (0,0) = 0 (since the game has 0 red and 0 blue balls to begin with; note: red means +1 and blue means -1). Now the (1,0) = 1 and (0,1) = 0. So now (2,0) = 2. (1,1) = (1/2)*(1+(0,1)) + (1/2)*(-1 + (1,0)) = 1/2. Is this correct?